# JSP $ sign what does it mean

Tags: jsp

```
<p>Greetings, it is now <c:out value="${now}"/></p>
```

In this jsp code what is the `$` sign actually doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Identifies it as an [expression](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0211.html), an expression is of the format `${....}`, so it's placing your `now` variable in the page (HTML encoded, since you're using `<c:out>`).

For the `<c:out>` encoding comment: You can grab [the full spec here](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr052/), or if you want to learn more about JSTL in general, [start here](https://jstl.dev.java.net/getStarted.html).

Comment: JSTL should not to be confused/mixed with EL.

Comment: @BalusC - I was referring to the `<c:out>` encoding comment, sorry that wasn't clear, updated.

Answer (score 1):

It's an [expression evaluation](http://tim.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/05/jsp.html).